# How to pass multiselect list's selected Items back to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am developing a MVC application which contains the multiselect dropdown list. 
I want to get the ID's of multiple selected items of the drop down.

I have the code in model

```
namespace CustomerDEMOForMultiselect.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        private int _ID;
        private string _Name;
        private double _Amt;
        public int ID { get { return _ID; } set { _ID = value; }  }
        public string Name { get { return _Name; } set { _Name = value ; } }
        public double Amt { get { return _Amt; } set { _Amt = value; } }
    }
}
```

And Controller Code is

```
namespace CustomerDEMOForMultiselect.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult DisplayCustomer()
        {
            Customer oCustomer = new Customer();
            List<Customer> CustomersList = new List<Customer>();
            CustomersList.Add(new Customer() { ID = 1, Name = "TestCustomer1", Amt = 123 });
            CustomersList.Add(new Customer() { ID = 2, Name = "TestCustomer2", Amt = 234 });
            CustomersList.Add(new Customer() { ID = 3, Name = "TestCustomer3", Amt = 324 });
            ViewBag.CustList = CustomersList;
            return View(CustomersList);
          }
    }
}
```

I am not getting what to write in View, I have tried different code but I am getting confusing...

Code in View:

```
@model CustomerDEMOForMultiselect.Models.Customer 
@{
    Layout = null;
} 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <title>DisplayCustomer</title> 
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div>
             @using (Html.BeginForm())
             {
                 @Html.DropDownListFor(v => v.ID, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.CustList,"ID","Name",ViewBag.ID)) 
                 <br /> 
                 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
             } 
        </div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

I want to show the `CustomerName list` in View , so I can select multiple customer name and pass those selected customer ID's back to controller. 
How to do that?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far in the view? Does your view reference the `CustomerList` as a model in the expected format? For example `@model IList<Customer>`. You should also declare the list as an `IList<Customer>` instead of `List<Customer>` in your code.

Comment: I have used following Code.                                                               `@model CustomerDEMOForMultiselect.Models.Customer

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>DisplayCustomer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
     
      
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
   { 
                   
        
 @Html.DropDownListFor(v => v.ID,new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.CustList,"ID","Name",ViewBag.ID))
                        
                   
   <br />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   }

    </div>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: I added that code to your question, easier to read :)

Answer (score 15):

Using a wrapper model with a property to bind the selected customers to works (I tried it):

Wrapper Model:

```
public class CustomerList
{
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedIDs { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult DisplayCustomer()
        {
            Customer oCustomer = new Customer();
            List<Customer> CustomersList = new List<Customer>();
            CustomersList.Add(new Customer() { ID = 1, Name = "TestCustomer1", Amt = 123 });
            CustomersList.Add(new Customer() { ID = 2, Name = "TestCustomer2", Amt = 234 });
            CustomersList.Add(new Customer() { ID = 3, Name = "TestCustomer3", Amt = 324 });
            ViewBag.CustList = CustomersList;
            return View(new CustomerList() { Customers = CustomersList }); 

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void DisplayCustomer(List<int> selectedIds)
        {
            // do something with the id list
        }
```

View:

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.CustomerList

@using (Html.BeginForm(@Model.SelectedIDs))
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedIDs, new MultiSelectList(@Model.Customers, "ID", "Name", @Model.SelectedIDs))
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
}
```

You need something to bind your selection to and send it back to the controller.

Comment: Thanks Nathalie Kellenberger, Where to add this wrapper class ?  In customer model itself ?

Comment: Whether I have to add view strongly typed ? I have created Empty view.I am geeting an error on `@Model.Customer` And error is 'System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList.MultiSelectList(System.Collections.IEnumerable, string, string, System.Collections.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: As a side-note, try to use the interfaces when declaring your properties instead of the conrecte implementations. i.e: Change `public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }` to `public IList<Customer> Customers { get; set; }` and so on.

Comment: The wrapper class is a model itself therefore you add it to the model folder. and you need to have a strongly typed view.

Comment: With this solution, we get the selected items from MultiSelectList. How can I get all items in MultiSelectList? I am using MultiSelectList with a list dynamically changing.